# Error deleting more than 1 row

Tags: sql-server, delete, errors

I have a stored procedure that is supposed to delete several rows from a table. It does not work and gives me the error:

```
The transaction ended in the trigger. The batch has been aborted
```

I tried running the individual queries to see if they would work separately. I found that the error is that it doesn't let me delete more than 1 row at a time. Here is an example:

```
DELETE FROM DetalleBusqueda
WHERE IdResultado IN (106577, 106578, 106579)
```

That query does not work, but the following one does:

```
DELETE FROM DetalleBusqueda
WHERE IdResultado IN (106577)
```

The first query is supposed to delete 3 rows, and the second one only 1 row. The second one does what it's supposed but the first one gives me the aforementioned error.

Does anyone have any idea what is it that I have to do so the procedure can delete more than a row at a time?

Comment: What is the target database management system?

Comment: Also, look at the table `DetalleBusqueda` Is a trigger on there?

Comment: Sounds like your trigger is coded to only expect one row in the `DELETED` table. Please post the code for the trigger.

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server does not support FOR EACH ROW clause in trigger.
So, I think that query in a trigger falls down with an error like this

Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Maybe replacement of "=" by "IN" will help.